# How to throw an exception for non-existence image choose

Tags: android

in my scenario I choose an picture from gallery and show it in my imageView on the same layout and i can process to another activity using the image. But i have an force stop when i didnt choose any image when click the intent button.

Who have the idea on solving this?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.browse_page);

    //action for browse Image

        Intent intent = new Intent();       
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);


    //declare image and button
    image = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.image);
    chooseNewImage = (Button) findViewById (R.id.chooseNewImage);
    grayScale = (Button) findViewById (R.id.greyscale);

    //back to previous page
    chooseNewImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    //go to set the image to grayScale
    grayScale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent greyScale = new Intent(browsePage.this, grayScale.class);
                greyScale.putExtra("imagePath", path_selectedImage);
                startActivity(greyScale);

        }
    }); 
}

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {


                    Uri_selectedImage = data.getData();
                    path_selectedImage = getPath(Uri_selectedImage);                   
                    image.setImageURI(Uri_selectedImage);
                    System.out.println(path_selectedImage);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your selected picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
             }


    }

    private String getPath(Uri uri) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] project = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor c = managedQuery(uri, project, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);
        int column_index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c.getString(column_index);


}
```

whenever i didnt choose an image and i press the grayscale button, it force stop. Is it need to put try-catch?

Comment: What do you want to happen when greyscale is clicked and no image is selected?  Or should you only enable the greyscale button when an image is selected?  Please also post the logcat of the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //go to set the image to grayScale     
 grayScale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {

          if (path_selectedImage==null){
             // show toast here
          } else {     
             Intent greyScale = new Intent(browsePage.this,grayScale.class);
             greyScale.putExtra("imagePath",path_selectedImage);
             startActivity(greyScale);          
       }
 });
```